# Ignore packagist.org and specify path for one bundle

Tags: symfony, composer-php, php-deployer

I modified a symfony 4 bundle to fix some bug. I now want to deploy my project through https://deployer.org/.

So I added this bundle not ignored in the .gitignore so that the folder of the bundle with my modifications is available on my github repo.

When executing the "`deploy`"  command of deployer, it executes the command "`/composer.phar install --verbose --prefer -dist --no-progress --no-interaction --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-suggest`" so that the folder of my bundle edit is overwritten by the original bundle folder from https://packagist.org/.

I would like to modify my composer.json to define the path of my modified bundle and that it is not overwritten.

Here is what I tried in the composer.json of my main project:

```
{
    "type": "my-project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/vendor/my/modifiedBundle",
            "packagist.org": false,
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        ......
        "my/modifiedBundle": "0.6.1",
        ......
    },
    "require-dev": {
        .....
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "my/modifiedBundle": "source",
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        ....
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": true,
            "require": "4.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the composer.json of my modified bundle:

```
{
  "name": "my/modifiedBundle",
  "type": "symfony-bundle",
  "license": "MIT",
  "require": {
    ...
  },
  "require-dev": {
    ...
  },
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "my\\modifiedBundle\\": ""
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "my\\modifiedBundle\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  }
}
```

But after my modifications, the modified bundle is still overwritten by the original bundle, do you have any idea?

Comment: I think you path sould not be absolute try: "url": "vendor/my/modifiedBundle"

But if it is a bundle available on GitHub, you should fork it, modify and refer to you fork.

Comment: @kl3sk it works very well with the fork, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Skros2 solved his problem on:

- Fork the bundle to its own repository
- Edit the fork
- Refer his fork on his `composer.json`project

how to [refer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#custom-vendor-alias) a fork.

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/foobar/intermediate.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "http://pear.foobar.repo",
            "vendor-alias": "foobar"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "foobar/TopLevelPackage1": "*",
        "foobar/TopLevelPackage2": "*"
    }
}
```